# How to handle unified relationships of different tables (eg. Customers/Companies and Addresses)

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I'll start of with what I have already:
[image: Version 1]

I've learned at uni how to create databases and now I'm trying to create my own for personal use and possible use for my customer base. The people I work for are on the one hand businesses (Companies) and on the other hand privates (Customers).

I tried to build my database like shown above. I want to be able to add multiple addresses to both my customers and companies. I also have several employees that work for me.

Now, I'm pretty happy with what I have right now but I have the feeling it can be simpler but with the same capabilities (multiple addresses, ...).

Secondly, both Companies and Customers can make orders. Right now I only have a table for Customers to place an order and I'm clueless how I can do the same for Companies.

Should I make a CustomerOrder and CompanyOrder table to achieve this or is there a better solution?

---

**EDIT**

I played around a little and actually started over. I tried to take each part like email, phone, fax and put it in its own table. This way, if I update a phone number somewhere and it's used elsewhere, both will be updated.

Below is what I have so far:

[image: Version 2]

Phone, Phone_1 and Phone_2 are the same table, Access just displays it that way. Any suggestions on how I'm doing? ContactType is used if there is CustomerSupport or TechnicalSupport. Type in EntityAddress is to determine if the Address is for a Person or a Company. This way it's expandable for more entities.

Now that I'm Writing this, would it be a good idea to do the same for Phone, Email and Fax like I do with Address?

Comment: This is actually a "tough" question - where to unify different relationships - and neither approach is perfect or complication-free with standard DRI as SQL does not support distributed foreign keys. I would definitely start with a joining table approach (e.g. Customers_Orders, Customer:M<->M:Order), but there is a subjective line to cross in more complex cases of this problem.

Comment: Are Companies and Customers subclasses of some identifiable superclass?  Are you trying to represent this by the relationships between tables?

Comment: Well, for the Order problem I can say yes, Customers and Companies can place Orders so they are pretty much handled the same. On the other hand Companies can have Employees but Customers can't. A Customer is not an Employee but both are People (Person table). A Customer can't work for a Company, but the Person behind the Customer can be an Employee working at a Company. Does this makes sense?

Comment: I edited my original post, does that look good or is it worse than it was?

Comment: @Krowi: [Customers] and [companies] can place order from your store. this means both should be called [customers] and their type could be private or company. Also why do you care if the company purchasing from you has employees? are you referring your own company as company?

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you is to create a separate table for orders with no link to either customers or to companies. Then you create 2 intermediate tables to link order and company together on the one hand and order and customers together on the other hand.

Fields in the table will look like:
LinkID
CustomerID / CompanyID
OrderID

It avoids having twice the same table (order table).

For the phones, you can do the same thing. This way you can have as many phone numbers as you like linked to one company or customer.